# How did 'wieldy', the positive form of 'unwieldy', come to be a non-existent word?

Tags: word-usage

I.e., is there a known reason behind why the negative form of the word 'wieldy', 'unwieldy', is so vastly used, whereas the positive form is essentially a non-existent word — [MacMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/spellcheck/british/?q=wieldy) doesn't even have an entry for it and the spell checker of my current browser is giving me a red squiggly line underneath that word?

The various on-line dictionaries I've consulted say 'wieldy' means '[easily controlled or handled](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wieldy?q=wieldy)', '[capable of being wielded easily](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wieldy)' (e.g., *wieldy weapon*, *wieldy car*, ...), and, as such, I expected that word to be common among native British or American speakers, but Google Books shows (only) 20,600 hits for it and 1,500,000 hits for 'unwieldy'.

Comment: The 'easily' (with facility) part is generally not recognized by the reader. *Wield* is to handle, whence *wieldy* is seen merely as 'that which can be handled'. To be really easy or comfortable to handle would be *handy*, *manageable*, *maneuverable* ... On the other hand, *unweildy* stresses on the antonymic prefix of the word stressing that it can't be handled well.

Comment: It's much the same with [*uncouth, ungainly, unkempt, unruly, unstinting, untoward,*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unpaired_word) etc.

Comment: You don't have "ruly mobs" (http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/2479058) or even "ruly kids" everyday. :)

Comment: We are also more familiar with a *ruthless* tyrant than a *ruth* caregiver.

Comment: Related: *[Is there a term for what 'sheveled' is to 'disheveled'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22443/is-there-a-term-for-what-sheveled-is-to-disheveled/82750#82750)*

Comment: Negatives often last longer than affirmatives. _Wieldy_ is a transparent derivation of _wield_, which, along with _wielding, wields,_ and _wielded_, has simply declined in use, for whatever reasons, except in fixed phrases. _Unwieldy_, on the other hand, is essentially glued-together fixed phrase that describes a particularly common and apt perception. So _unwieldy_ has gone on living its own independent life as a word in the language. This is normal. I often think of Negative Polarity as a "poet's corner" of the language; very ancient forms mixed with upstart slang, all having a good party.

Comment: Because "wieldy" is too unwieldy a word to describe "easy".

Answer (score 7):

A bit of reflection should show that a commoner **attribute** makes for a less common **word**. *Flightless birds* are in the minority, so the adjective is needed; in most cases the term for *flighted birds* is just *birds*.  A hammer or sword is designed to be wielded, so is expcetd to be wieldy; only when particularly large or badly made is it unwieldy, and hence worth remarking on.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard the verb "to wield" referring to handling a sword or weapon, and wieldy (adv) is just the adjective.  I would assume more attention would be paid to an unwieldy object, since a "wieldy" object would not need the same reference as being haphazard.

Answer (score 1):

> **Wieldy**
>
> - Easily handled

I think this word choice is perfectly correct, according to the Oxford dictionary, although not much in use.

Etymologically, "to wield" means "to have power upon, to possess", more than it means "to hold a weapon or a tool and being able to use it".